# Jquery with autocomplete trigger after selecting an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to use the autocomplete jquery API. The issue is I want to trigger a function or a set of code once I selected an item but i keep getting undefined items.

Here my code:

```
function init()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('event_address');
    var options = 
    {
      types: ['geocode']
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    // event triggered when drop-down option selected
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var address = document.getElementById(event_address).value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                alert(results[0].geometry.locations);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here my errors:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Thanks

Comment: where is the jquery in your code?

Comment: Why are you using the ":" in `select: function(event, ui) {`, and just why are you formatting it that way? No `var`? Using a keyword (`select`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I believe what you are referring to is jqueryUI's autocomplete widget.  The `select` method fires when an autocomplete selection has been made.  I'm assuming what you're trying to do would be to display the coordinates of a geographical region chosen from the auto complete list.

you would need to do something like this:

```
$('#inputbox').autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui){
     // code to get selection
     var address = $('#inputbox').text();
     //assuming your geocode is correct
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            alert(results[0].geometry.locations);
        }
    });
   }

});
```

For more info, see the autocomplete documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select